# Swift Completion Blocks with Closures using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, afnetworking

Using Objective C, I'm used to have this method to encapsulate GET method from AFHTTPSessionManager and get information from an API JSON:

```
- (void)getShowInfo:(void(^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                 failure:(void(^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
{

    NSString* path = kInfoBaseURLString;


    [self GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(task, responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(task, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

How can I do it in Swift, comparing the success and failure? I was trying something like:

```
func getShowInfo(success: (task: NSURLSessionDataTask, responseObject: AnyObject) -> Void,
       failure: (task: NSURLSessionDataTask, error: NSError) -> Void) {

    var path : String = kInfoBaseURLString

    GET(path, parameters: nil, success: {(task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        if (success != nil) {
            success(task, responseObject)
        }
        success = nil
    }, failure: {(task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) in
        if (failure != nil) {
            failure(task, error)
        }    
    })
}
```

everything inside "if (success !=nil)"  and "if (failure != nil)" is not working.

How to convert it to swift?

Edited to complete with the errors:

```
if (success != nil) {
```

error: '(task: NSURLSessionDataTask, responseObject: AnyObject) -> Void' is not convertible to 'String'

```
if (failure != nil) {
```

error: '(task: NSURLSessionDataTask, error: NSError) -> Void' is not convertible to 'String'

```
success(task, responseObject)
```

error: Missing argument labels 'task:responseObject:' in call

```
failure(task, error)
```

error: Missing argument labels 'task:responseObject:' in call

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks, you save my day! I get trapped in how to write completion handler in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

With the method as defined in Swift, you can't pass nil success or failure closures, so the check is not necessary. If you *can* pass nil, then the success or failure parameters need to be marked as optionals in the method definition.

I'd suggest using Alamofire instead of AFNetworking for a Swift project, unless you've already tied yourself to AFNetworking.